# How does Unsafe library help atomic variables to achieve thread safety?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, compare-and-swap

I've been reading web articles about how Compare and Swap (CAS) works under the hood. Since AtomicInteger, AtomicLong and other atomic variables all use JNI's "Unsafe" library's compareAndSet() method, but when you go to the actual implementation, you'll get a blank, abstract-like method below which does not tell you how compareAndSet() is actually thread-safe.

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public final native boolean compareAndSetLong(Object o, long offset,
                                              long expected,
                                              long x);
```

Has anyone wondered how JNI's Unsafe library guarantees thread safety for atomic variables?

Comment: There's two hints in that signature: `native` means that the code isn't implemented in Java (it can't be), but in native (C++) code instead. And `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` means it isn't even a regular native method, but one that's implemented with a deep integration into the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Note that JNI and Unsafe are unrelated: Unsafe is not part of JNI and, as already pointed out, despite the native methods, Unsafe is not implemented with JNI.

It's directly [linked](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+6/src/hotspot/share/prims/unsafe.cpp#L886) in the [VM](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+6/src/hotspot/share/prims/unsafe.cpp#L748) to some generic [`Atomic::cmpxchg`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+6/src/hotspot/share/runtime/atomic.hpp#L747) which you then have to trace through some [layers](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+6/src/hotspot/share/runtime/atomic.hpp#L768) of templates to the appropriate [implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+6/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/atomic_linux_x86.hpp#L126) depending on your platform (here linux-amd64).

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is rather straightforward.
There are two parts to it: a JNI method that makes the instruction available as part of bytecode-interpreted evaluation, and an intrinsic that makes it available when the JIT compiler generates native code.

## JNI method

unsafe.cpp shows the [implementation as a JNI method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/prims/unsafe.cpp#L748-L752):

```
UNSAFE_ENTRY(jboolean, Unsafe_CompareAndSetLong(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jobject obj, jlong offset, jlong e, jlong x)) {
  oop p = JNIHandles::resolve(obj);
  volatile jlong* addr = (volatile jlong*)index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p, offset);
  return Atomic::cmpxchg(addr, e, x) == e;
} UNSAFE_END
```

Atomic::cmpxchg [dispatches](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/atomic.hpp#L744-L842) to various strategies for doing a CAS, and you find the actual implementation  in terms of assembly instructions in an [OS+CPU specific file](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/atomic_linux_x86.hpp):

```
template<>
template<typename T>
inline T Atomic::PlatformCmpxchg<4>::operator()(T volatile* dest,
                                                T compare_value,
                                                T exchange_value,
                                                atomic_memory_order /* order */) const {
  STATIC_ASSERT(4 == sizeof(T));
  __asm__ volatile ("lock cmpxchgl %1,(%3)"
                    : "=a" (exchange_value)
                    : "r" (exchange_value), "a" (compare_value), "r" (dest)
                    : "cc", "memory");
  return exchange_value;
}
```

There are also implementations for 1-byte and 8-byte CAS, but the only difference is `cmpxchgb` and `cmpxchgq`, respectively.

## JVM Intrinsic

As remarked in the comments to your question, the method is also tagged with `@HotspotIntrinsicCandidate`. (`@IntrinsicCandidate` in recent JVMs).
The JVM keeps a [list of all intrinsic candidates](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/classfile/vmIntrinsics.hpp) by class and method name. The [class file parser](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#L5161-L5254) associates the method with the declared intrinsic. From there, the JIT compiler can detect calls to methods with intrinsics and replace them with inlined versions or assembly fragments for just that instruction.